# Referring to article names in text

Tags: citations

I've found lots of documentation on in-text bracketed citations and referencing list styles, but very little on the following.

When referring to names of articles in text, should the article name be surrounded by quotation marks?

For example:

> In 1990, John Smith presented his work: "A question on quotation marks".

Or, alternatively:

> In 1990, John Smith presented his work: A question on quotation marks.

In my case, the required referencing style is ACM format, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research your question, it appears from multiple universities that the proper way to reference a source in text with ACM format is:

> So we see that Smith [1990] ...

Therefore you should not need to reference the actual article name.

https://biblioteca.info.unlp.edu.ar/uploads/docs/guia_acm1.pdf
https://www.cs.ucy.ac.cy/~chryssis/specs/ACM-refguide.pdf
https://www.library.unh.edu/research-support/citation-styles/acm-style